# WPF bound ComboBox with CompositeCollection - setting SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a bound WPF comboBox that has an ItemsSource set to a CompositeCollection.  I'm trying this to try and accomodate adding <Select> and <Add New...> selections to precede an ObservableCollection of 'regular' objects.  What I can't figure out is how to, in code-behind, select one of these added choices.

This is how I'm building the CompositeCollection:

```
private CompositeCollection CreateItemsSource(ObservableCollection<T> source)
{
  CompositeCollection cmpc = new CompositeCollection();

  cmpc.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "<Select>" });
  cmpc.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "<Add New...>" });

  var cc1 = new CollectionContainer { Collection = source };
  cmpc.Add(cc1);

  return cmpc;
}
```

This is what the ComboBox looks like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LookupComboTemplate">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>

  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategories.ItemsSource}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LookupComboTemplate}">
    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
      <Binding Path="SourceData.SubCategoryObj" Mode="TwoWay"></Binding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
  </ComboBox>
```

I've got a situation where SelectedItem SourceData.SubCategoryObj is null (it's an optional property).  In this case, I want to manually select and display the <Select> choice.  But no matter what I do (setting SelectedIndex is ignored, setting SelectedValue to the ComboBoxItem in the CompositeCollection is ignored) I get a blank ComboBox when it renders.

I'd appreciate any advice on how I can do this.

Thanks!
Corey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fix this with a custom valueconverter  for your SelectedItem binding. http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html should give you some pointers.

I'm not sure if combox wants a simple string or some composite object but you can check that. Something like

```
public class ComboConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "<Select>";
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.toString().Equals("<Select>")
            return null;
        return value;
    }
```

should give you the "<Select>" entry if the selected item is null.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  If I am using a ValueConverter, what am I converting from and what am I converting to?  To/from a ComboBoxItem, to/from my ObservableCollection<T>, or to/from a string?  The link gives me a direction, but I need a little more info on how to apply it in my situation.

Comment: You probably won't "really" convert, but rather add your special entries in case the selectedvalue is null. I've added an example to the answer. You probably need to change the simply "Select" string to a combobox item but it should point you in the right direction.